# How to calculate a blosum matrix with X% identity?

Tags: sequence-analysis

Calculating a blosum matrix is easy and many explanations online exist. However, given a set of sequences and asked to get X% identity I am unsure of.

Say they said 80% identity with the following sequences:

```
DADAA
DCDAA
DCDAD
CCAAA
CCAAD
```

The first step is to note there are 2 groups with 80% identity:

```
First Group with 3 sequence:
DADAA
DCDAA
DCDAD
```

and

```
Second Group with 3 sequence:
CCAAA
CCAAD
```

So my understanding is that this means for the first group each sequence contributes 1/3 and for the second group each contributes 1/2

So we start with number of A to A (N_AA) starting at the first left column;

*But this is what I am not 100% sure of*, ***how to count them as weighted per group***:

I think:

```
0 + 0 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 4*(1/3)(1/2) + 1/3 + 2*(1/3)(1/2)
```

the logic here is:

```
1st column: 0 
2nd column: 0 
3rd column: A-A in the second group: 1/2
4th column: A-A in the first group AND 4 of A first group to second group: 1/3 + 4*(1/3)(1/2)
5th column: A-A in the first group AND 2 of A first group to second group: 1/3 + 2*(1/3)(1/2)
```

Is this calculation correct?

Comment: Is this the same question you were trying to ask before, or a different one? (If it's the same we can delete the old one)

Comment: this is step 1 of the other question with a specific problem as requested.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this, is to collapse the similar (X%) sequences st:

```
DADAA
DCDAA
DCDAD
```

becomes:

```
D[A(1/3),C(2/3)]DA[A(2/3),D(1/3)]
```

and the other segment:

```
CCAAA
CCAAD
```

becomes:

```
CCAA[A(1/2),D(1/2)]
```

Now we have start counting.

For col 1 for example: N_DC = 1

For col 2 for example: N_AC = 1 & N_CC =1

For col 3 for example: N_DA = 1

For col 4 for example: N_AA = 1

For col 5 for example: N_AD = 0.5, N_AA = 0.5, N_DA = 0.5, & N_DD = 0.5

now we can proceed with the rest of BLOSUM calculations...

Comment: For completeness, please include how gaps in a multiple sequence alignment are conventionally handled.